# Tap UIImageView with no alpha response?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, transparency, alpha

I have an image which has a relatively large area of transparency, alpha space. So is there a way I can detect a tap on this `UIImageView` but not have any response if the user taps the alpha area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is theoretical and I don't have code to add, but you could create an identical button and add it for UIControlStateTouched so there's no change when the button/image is touched.

Comment: You've lost me. I want this image to act like a button, however I don't want any response if the user taps a transparent part of the image.

Comment: Make the image instead of an image a UIButton with a custom image, then make that image have a a view for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateTouched so that if someone touches it, it looks the same as if they didn't.